# want to add variations of product in cart under the title of product in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i want to add all of variations of product that customer chose, under the product title
for ex
size: xxl
color:blue

and its important to be under the title.
can any one write the code? some kind of code that i place in cart.php under the product_title
thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
function display_product_variations_in_cart($product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key) {
if (!empty($cart_item['variation_id']) && is_array($cart_item['variation'])) {
$variations_text = '';

foreach ($cart_item['variation'] as $variation_key => $variation_value) {
$variation_label = wc_attribute_label(str_replace('attribute_', '', $variation_key));
$variations_text .= $variation_label . ': ' . $variation_value . ', ';
}

$variations_text = rtrim($variations_text, ', ');

// Append the variations to the product title
$product_name .= '<br><small>' . $variations_text . '</small>';
}

return $product_name;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'display_product_variations_in_cart', 10, 3);
```